# Let $f\in C^1[-1,1] $. Evaluate $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f'(\frac k{3n} ) $ [NBHM 2012]

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f\in C^1[-1,1] $. Evaluate
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}f'\left (\frac k{3n}\right ) $

Thinking: I was thinking to apply $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \sum_{r=1}^{n}f\left (\frac rn \right) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \mathrm dx$.
But unable to apply. Please tell me if I am wrong, if there is any other way then also please teach me that.

Comment: Is there a factor $1/n$ missing? Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2106111/42969 .

Comment: @MartinR My question reads the one I have posted. There is no $\frac 1n$. So, I don't know if that was the actual question!

Comment: In the other thread it is shown that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n}f'\left (\frac k{3n}\right ) = 3\left(f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-f(0)\right)$. Which means that your expression has no finite limit (unless $f(1/3) = f(0)$).